# Problems installing Adobe Flash player

Tags: flash, flash-player

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit) and IE9 and Adobe Flash player (10.3.183.5 final for IE&AOL) but I can not watch video on YouTube and other sites.

Why?

Comment: have you tried other browsers - also get the main release?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying another browser, especially if it is a work machine.  Youtube is trivial to block on a work machine.